# type specifier error

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int b=10;
//b=100;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
   cout<<b<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

There is an error if remove the comment at `b = 100`.Why is that so.The output is 10 otherwise.
error:C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations.

Comment: You can't perform assignments outside of a function, but you can initialise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The global scope can only contain declarations and definitions, not arbitrary statements.

C++ thinks you're trying to declare and define another variable called `b`.

Answer (score 1):

An expression statement (like `b=100;`) must be inside a function.

Outside a function, you can declare and initialise variables, but you can't directly execute arbitrary code.

You get that particular error because the compiler interprets the code as a declaration with no type specifier (i.e. `int b=100;` with the `int` missing), rather than as an expression statement where it's not expecting such a thing. Such a declaration is allowed in C (although in this case, it would fail because there's already a variable called `b`), but not in C++.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign to a variable in global scope, except when initialising it.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do

```
b = 100;
```

inside main. You can't change an already declared variable outside a function.

Answer (score 0):

Any statement should occurred inside a function. Global variable can be defined and initialize   outside functions body. but assignment should be within some function body.