# Error to use of static and static function in C++

Tags: c++, static, static-methods, clion, non-static

i am beginner in programming, start C++ one weak ago. i have problem to use of my static variable. i read about use of static variable in various same question but i understand just this **Car::countOfInput;**. from below post:

1. [How do I call a static method of another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365982/how-do-i-call-a-static-method-of-another-class)
2. [C++ Static member method call on class instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325555/c-static-member-method-call-on-class-instance)
3. [How to call static method from another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300449/how-to-call-static-method-from-another-class)

this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class Car{
    private:
        static int countOfInput;
        char   *carName;
        double carNumber;
    public:
        Car() {
            static int countOfInput = 0;
            char carName = {'X'};
            double carNumber = 0;
        }

        void setVal(){
            double number;

            cout << "Car Name: ";
            char* str = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
            cin>>str;
            strcpy(carName, str);

            cout << endl << "Car Number: ";
            cin >> number; cout << endl;
            carNumber = number;

            Car::countOfInput += 1;
       }

       friend void print(){
            if(Car::countOfInput == 0){
                cout << "Error: empty!";
                return;
            }
            cout << "LIST OF CarS" << endl;
            cout << "Car Name: " << carName << "\t";
            cout << "Car Number: " << carNumber << endl;
      } const

      void setCarNumber(int x){carNumber = x;}
      int  getCarNumber(){return carNumber;}

      void setcarName(char x[]){strcpy(carName, x);}
      char getcarName(){return *carName;}

      int getCountOfInput(){return countOfInput;}
      void setCountOfInput(int x){countOfInput = x;}
};

int main(){
    Car product[3];
    product[0].setVal();
    product[0].print();

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

when i run this:

> F:\CLion\practise\main.cpp: In function 'void print()':
>
> F:\CLion\practise\main.cpp:10:13: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'Car::carName'
>        char   *carName;
>                ^
>
> F:\CLion\practise\main.cpp:40:33: error: from this location
>            cout << "Car Name: " << carName << "\t";
>                                    ^
>
> F:\CLion\practise\main.cpp:11:12: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'Car::carNumber'
>        double carNumber;
>               ^
>
> F:\CLion\practise\main.cpp:41:35: error: from this location
>            cout << "Car Number: " << carNumber << endl;
>                                      ^
>
> F:\CLion\practise\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>
> F:\CLion\practise\main.cpp:57:16: error: 'class Car' has no member named 'print'
>        product[0].print();

I use CLion, Thanks in advance.

Comment: If a class variable is marked `static`, it isn't associated with _any_ instance of its class. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Roughly, i want increase **count** of my static variable every time `setVal()` function call.

Comment: I think you need to take much smaller steps.  You have built up a mass of at least four separate errors here - writing less code and testing earlier would have simplified this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable declaration inside `Car()` are local variables, not initializations of the member variables. To initialize the member variables, just do this (it's a [member initializer list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1711990/3425536)):

```
Car() : carName("X"), carNumber(0) {}
```

and put the definition of `countOfInput` outside the class in a .cpp file (in global scope):

```
int Car::countOfInput = 0;
```

(If you want to reset `countOfInput` to `0` every time the `Car()` constructor is called, you can do that in the constructor body: `countOfInput = 0;`)

Comment: Ooooo, nice catch with locals. :) Seems like a quiz question from school.

Comment: What can i do if i want to have my `print` function be `friend`?

Comment: @DeathProgrammer Declare it friend inside the class and define it outside, like normally.

Answer (score 3):

The error messages have nothing to do with static variables or static methods.

The keyword `friend` is in front of `print()`, make it a non-member function (note the last error message) and then can't access the member variables directly. According to the usage it should be a member function, so just remove the keyword `friend`.

And as @tuple_cat suggested, `const` should be put before the beginning `{`.

```
void print() const {
     if(Car::countOfInput == 0){
         cout << "Error: empty!";
         return;
     }
     cout << "LIST OF CarS" << endl;
     cout << "Car Name: " << carName << "\t";
     cout << "Car Number: " << carNumber << endl;
 }
```

Comment: And put `const` before the opening `{`.

Comment: without `friend` and even `const` and even put `const` before the beginninng, not working yet.

Comment: Give me this error: _F:/CLion/practise/main.cpp:31: undefined reference to `Car::countOfInput'_.

Comment: @DeathProgrammer It's another issue. See tuple_cat's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Oh dear.  You have a number of problems.  Firstly, your constructor doesn't initialize any of the member variables.

```
   Car() {
        static int countOfInput = 0;
        char carName = {'X'};
        double carNumber = 0;
    }
```

Instead it is declaring three local variables and setting them to values.  What you want is:

```
   Car() 
       : carName(nullptr)
       , carNumber(0.0) 
   {
   }
```

Then `setValue` is copying the string into the memory pointed at by `this->carName`, but that is uninitialized, so could be anywhere.  Also, `strlen(str)` before you initialize `str` is doomed to failure.  Make `carName` a std::string, then you don't need to construct it, and the code becomes:

```
   Car() 
       : carNumber(0.0) 
   {
   }

   void setVal(){

        cout << "Car Name: ";
        cin >> carName;

        cout << endl << "Car Number: ";
        cin >> carNumber; cout << endl;

        Car::countOfInput += 1;
   }
```

Next, you need to make `print` not be a friend (and make it const).

```
   void print() const {
   ...
```

Finally you need to define `coutOfInput`.  You have declared it, but you also need a definition.  Outside any function do:

```
int Car::countOfInput = 0;
```